# Time-passage callback when rendering recorded and live/streaming audio/video

Tags: video, audio, events, callback, frame

Guys...! I'm a complete newbie to this area of audio/video formats/codecs, their players, their exposed APIs, etc. Would greatly appreciate your patience as well as advice on this question of mine.

**Question:** Almost all audio/video players show time-passage information in hh:mm:ss format. I want to be able to register a callback of mine -- which could either be a Java/applet callback or a Javascript callback -- which gets called at every 'time tick' and runs my custom code. Perhaps it's not a time tick but a 'frame-passage' event in the lingo of codecs. Perhaps, these codecs/players allow you to even specify the frequency of callback (every so many frames or seconds)...

Secondly, I wish to be able to do this for both recorded content as well as live/streaming content.

What opensource software, tools, APIs, 'concepts', etc I should be looking at? I'd like to be able to handle the most popular formats such as flv, avi, mp3, mpeg. Ideally, I would prefer to deal with something in Java / Javascript.

Not sure where to start. A sample, a code snippet, or even just the process/steps I need to follow would be a great help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what kinds of environment you are running in and the kinds of things you want to do in your callback.  Some multimedia frameworks have a way to add video, subtitle, or audio filters, which have access to the various data from the stream.  One such open source framework is [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).  Another is the Java-based [Processing](http://processing.org/) language, although it cannot directly decode popular video formats on its own.  I think that [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/), which of course is the open source king of video formats, also has an API that could potentially meet your needs.

The new [HTML5 video element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html) defines a `timeupdate` event, which will fire every 15 to 250ms while the video is playing.  The `currentTime` attribute can be accessed to get the current playback position.  It is also possible to [manipulate the HTML5 video directly in JavaScript code](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Manipulating_video_using_canvas).

If you just want a time callback while the video is playing and do not need to filter the data then you could just use the standard timer facilities of your language, e.g. `setTimeout()` in JavaScript, to request a timer callback at the frame rate of the video.